# Does POST section error makes Pipeline run unsuccessful?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cicd, cloudbees

I was going through [Cloudbees Training Documentation](https://university.cloudbees.com/path/certified-jenkins-engineer-cje-exam-preparation/jenkins-pipeline-1-essentials-community-version/1570540) for jenkins certification. In one of the section for `Post` it's mentioned that

> An error in a post section does not make the Pipeline run unsuccessful

[image]

As I was unsure of this, I tried to create a simple pipeline and making it fail in `Post` section but as I was expecting it made the pipeline failed in red.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                // Get some code from a GitHub repository
                git 'https://github.com/jglick/simple-maven-project-with-tests.git'

            }
        }
    }
    
    post {
        success {
            error("Build failed because of this and that..")
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Am I missing something in that statement or statement itself is wrong?